# How to include a default parameter in my member functions?

Tags: c++

I am making a program with an object of class Date. When I am printing the date of my class to the screen there are three options Default (M/D/Y), Long (month, day year), and Two-Digit (mm/dd/yy). I have solved the code for each option but I am having trouble changing the format when I call my SetFormat() function. I want the default parameter of SetFormat to be 'D' so that when there is no specified parameter it is in the Default form, but when SetFormat() is called in main it switches forms.

This is part of my .cpp file:

```cpp
void Date::Show()
{
        if (SetFormat('D'))
        {
            cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << year;
        }
        if (SetFormat('T'))
        {
            if(month < 10){
                cout << 0 << month << '/';
            }else
                cout << month << '/';
            if (day < 10) {
                cout << 0 << day << '/' << (year % 100);
            } else
                cout << day << '/' << (year % 100);
        }
        if (SetFormat('L'))
        {
            LongMonth();
            cout << " " << day << ", " << year;
        }
}

bool Date::SetFormat(char f)
{
    format = f;
    if (f == 'T')
        return true;
    if (f == 'D')
        return true;
    if (f == 'L')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is part of my .h file:

```cpp
class Date{
public:
    explicit Date(int m = 1, int d = 1, int y = 2000);
    void Input();
    void Show();
    bool Set(int m, int d, int y);
    bool SetFormat(char f = 'D');
```

The program is kind of just ignoring my 'if' statements right now and when I call the function SetFormat() in main it prints all 3 formats backtobacktoback.

Comment: SetFormat returns `true` for each of those `if` statements.

Comment: How do I make it so that it looks at each case individually? I am calling them each individually in main. Right now to test I have 3 objects... d1, d2, and d3 and I am calling d1.SetFormat() to test the default format, d2.SetFormat('L') and d3.SetFormat('T')

Comment: You've written a function which returns true if the input is T, D, or L. Then you call it with T, D, and L and seem confused when it returns true. I honestly don't understand where the confusion is arising from.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `SetFormat()` both as a "set" function as well as a "get" function. I suggest having two functions.

```
void SetFormat(char f);
char GetFormat() const;
```

and use them appropriately.

In `Date::Show()`, use `GetFormat()` or simply the value of member variable.
In `main`, use `SetFormat()`.

```
void Date::Show()
{
   // Need only one of the two below.
   // char f = GetFormat();
   char f = format;
   if (f == 'D')
   {
      cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << year;
   }
   else if (f == 'T')
   {
      if(month < 10){
         cout << 0 << month << '/';
      }else
         cout << month << '/';
      if (day < 10) {
         cout << 0 << day << '/' << (year % 100);
      } else
         cout << day << '/' << (year % 100);
   }
   else if ( f == 'L')
   {
      LongMonth();
      cout << " " << day << ", " << year;
   }
}

void Date::SetFormat(char f)
{
   format = f;
}

char Date::GetFormat() const
{
   return format;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
Date date;
date.SetFormat('L');
date.Show();
```

Of course, you should checks in `SetFormat()` and `Show()` to make sure that the format  is valid and do something if that is not the case.

Comment: Similar to the title of my question, how do I add a default parameter so that if I don't SetFormat before I call the Show() function it still shows in the Default form?

Comment: @HenryV, initialize the member variable `format` appropriately in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

the SetFormat(char) function returns true for every option, so it will print each one in turn.

Comment: In the instructions it says "If an invalid setting code is passed in, do not alter the current format setting.  This function should return true for successful format change, and false for failure (invalid setting given)." How do I change it so that it doesn't return true for each value

Comment: First, you always change the state rather or not the code is 'invalid' because your first step is 'format = f' regardless. You would be better off using a 'switch' statement than all the 'if' statements, where you have case 'D': case 'T': case 'L': format=f; return true; break; default: default: return false. Every value you pass in in Show is a valid value though, so you will get all those prints.